# How to upload videos in spring boot - Angular 6 Application?

Tags: node.js, angular, spring-boot, file-upload, jhipster

I'm working on spring boot / Angular 6 application with Jhipster framework, in this project the user will upload videos in the platform, so, how can I test the upload file in the development? The file will be uploaded and saved in a folder in the node server or in the tomcat server ? When I will deploy the project in a real server, how is it going to be done this procedure? The servers of node and tomcat will be deployed ?? I'm a beginner in spring boot and angular and I need your help please.

Answer (score 1):

if you're writing your backend with spring boot then you have to take care of the uploaded file in the spring boot restful controller; upload the the file via multipart in yoyr angular app( you can search uploading files multipart in google) and then receive the file in you're controller(search multipart spring boot) save the file where ever you want via java's File classes